# How it comes that authorized_keys exist on my Vagrant Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant

From my playbook folder I run

```
vagrant up
```

Vagrantfile is simple

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"

end
```

I can not copy my key

```
ssh-copy-id vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2200
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 3 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
vagrant@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I can ssh this way

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2200 -i .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

then I checked authorized_keys(on vagrant@ubuntu-focal)

```
cat authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2E************* vagrant
```

How to find out how ssh-rsa is created?

Comment: this seems like a Vagrant question?

Comment: @user253751 I do not understand SSH on deeper level.

Comment: something put the authorized_keys file there; it was probably Vagrant; I assume the matching file `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key` was also put there by Vagrant seeing as it's in a folder called .vagrant and relates to a virtualbox machine created by Vagrant.

Comment: @user253751 yes,but I created the same one with Redhat and there is no .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key.

Comment: then I guess Vagrant doesn't know how to do it with Redhat?